# Debug Excel VSTO add-in when launched by double-clicking existing file

Tags: excel, debugging, visual-studio-2013, vsto

I have a bug in an Excel VSTO 4.0 C# add-in that I've developed but it is only occurring when double-clicking on an existing file to launch Excel.  I'm trying to figure out a way to start the VS2013 debugger so that I can put in some breakpoints but none of the ways I've tried to start the debugger mimic the process of launching Excel by a double-click on a file.

Ways I've tried so far:

- Launching Excel itself and then attaching to the process
- Double-clicking an Excel file and then attaching to the resulting process
- In the VS project Debug properties under Start Action, entering the path to Excel Excel.exe in the Start external program box and the path to an existing Excel file in the command line arguments box
- Adding Excel.exe as a new existing project to my VS solution with the path to an existing file as an argument in the project properties, the setting it as the startup project for the solution.

None of these methods for starting the debugger are reproducing the bug.  Is there another way to start debugging when double-clicking a file to launch Excel?

For what it's worth, the bug I'm experiencing is that an empty workbook will be created when double-clicking an existing file when Excel is not already running.  I need to find out where / why that empty file is getting created.  It doesn't happen if Excel is already running and you double-click a file to open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use any logging mechanisms to log any action in the code. Thus, you will be able to find what is going on in the code at runtime. For example, you can write actions to the log file. You may find the [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) library helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've thought of that but it's very cumbersome and would add a lot of code that I'd rather not have in there.  I've had to do this to an extent as a workaround.

Comment: There is other way except those you described.

Comment: Accepting this for now since this is the method I did end up using.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are puuting breakpoint in a method which handles the WorkbookOpen event.

When you double click an Excel file, it gets loaded and event WorkbookOpen is raised. VSTO add-in is not yet loaded so you can't get that event. After loading the workbook, Excel loads VSTO add-in.

So when your add-in is loaded, your handler for AddinStartup comes in action.
In vb.net, the handler line appears as...

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
```

You can now check for loaded workbook in ThisAddIn_Startup

```
If Application.ActiveWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
    DoSomething(Application.ActiveWorkbook)
End If
```

The other way to mimic some of these debugging is to open file and close file, loading and unloading your addin using excel options manually.

1. Put a breakpoint on Addin_Startup.
2. Start normal debugging of VSTO Project.
3. Load File.
4. Go in excel options and unload your addin by unchecking it.
5. Go in excel options and LOAD your addin by checking it.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my case.  I need to put breakpoints in before WorkbookOpen is raised.  When double-clicking a file to open Excel ThisAddin_Startup gets called before the file is loaded.  It's during operations in ThisAddin_Startup is doing its thing.

Comment: @squillman You should avoid processing a workbook in ThisAddin_Startup, rather add a handler on WorkbookOpen event in this method.When the file gets loaded, the workbookopen handler will be called and you can the file there. Further I am editing my answer to give another way of mimicking the things you are trying.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate you looking at this.  I'm not actually processing a workbook, but I do need a reference to the active workbook.  I have some UI elements in a task pane that need to be associated with a workbook as the addin is being initialized.  I did find a solution to the exception I was getting by using logging, but I'm still hoping to find a hack that will allow the debugger to be used.  I'm going to try your new idea now.

Comment: Darn, I had hope for your new method.  Unfortunately, though, a new Excel process starts when I double-click a file after having started my addin in the debugger and the new process does not get attached to the debugger...